# New Wordpress install with very long response waiting time

Tags: php, wordpress, server-response

My website has a long response time (3 sec).

[image]

I tried deactivating all plugins one-by-one and checking, but it's waiting time is 2 sec.

I also use w3-cache and `wp-cache` on my live domain, but waiting time is 3 sec.

Today I downloaded the new WordPress, and configured all settings.

I did not add any themes or plugins and tested its speed; I see the WordPress waiting time is 2 sec.

[image]

It means my WordPress response time is long. How can I reduce it?

Comment: is it hosted from your localhost? might be your computer taking too much time to process the request? If it's live, have you tried online speed testing service (i.e. http://www.webpagetest.org/ ) to make sure it's not your internet?

Comment: the single best thing you can do is get it behind varnish or fastly, and learn how to invalidate pages caches on content updates. also make sure you have something like APC active. If implementing a real caching layer is not possible, try switching to wp-rocket and cloudflare, which work well in tandem

Answer (score 6):

[Some pretty high traffic sites run WordPress](http://vip.wordpress.com/clients/).

There are several layers in the technology stack that could be the problem. The most common bottlenecks are network speed, server resources (RAM/CPU), and database resources.

Since your initial page is very slow and your resources seem faster, I would probably eliminate network speed as an issue.  If you try loading a static HTML test page that'll confirm your network speed is okay.

Next, install [WP Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) on your **plain install** of WordPress using the default theme.  Is it fast?  If so, I would suspect your host's MySQL server is overloaded and overworked.

Answer (score 2):

By default most web hosts and WP aren't setup for 100% speed efficiency but with little tweaks you can make massive improvements in speed times.

I use [GTmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/) to measure a websites speed, and implement their ideas to increase the speed including:

[Htaccess GZip](http://salscode.com/tutorials/2009/10/15/gzip-htaccess/)

[Defer Javascript loading](http://uzelac.com/defer-parsing-of-javascript-for-wordpress/)

[Minify JS and CSS with Autoptimize](http://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/)

[reduce image size with Smush.it](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/)

They are only a couple of ways, GTmetrix will help you understand what is slowing your site down and ways to increase it.

Answer (score 0):

A default WordPress install should be lightning fast if it's on an even remotely decent server. Try removing the database, recreating it, and reinstalling. Or, use [phpMyAdmin to repair and optimize](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin_optimize_database.htm) your tables. If this is not an option, try some janitoral DB queries like:

```
DELETE FROM `user_meta` um LEFT JOIN `users` u ON (um.user_id = u.ID) WHERE u.ID IS NULL
```

Same concept with posts & post meta, just different primary keys.

Also, if your server is not setup properly for caching, i.e. XCache or memcache not installed, properly configured, or loaded, and you're not running an uber high-traffic site, you probably don't even really need to use caching at all. If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Or, if you have existing data that you cannot afford to lose, use [WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) to back up your existing install exporting to SQL file, follow steps above in regards to removing the original database, then import the database anew from phpMyAdmin after recreating.

Answer (score 0):

Getting desired performance from your Wordpress sites can be trick, as the Wordpress platform don't seem to have had performance optimizations in mind.

You can get the desired results by looking into performance optimization techniques- which can be done manually on your sites, but can be burdensome for the not so technical Wordpress users, especially if they just what a fast performing wordpress blog.

There are really good plugins out there that can make it easy but some still require technical knowledge. I recommend these 2 plugins and they are quite easier to configure for not so technical users.

[Speed up your website with jch optimize](https://www.jch-optimize.net/) - this plugin makes it really easy for combining, minifying css, javascript, and html. there ton more features you can get with the paid version.

[cache your site with W3TC](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) - one the most popular caching plugins. A must get if you want some extra speed.